# Return previous month's date and year VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, date

I need to retrieve today's previous month and year as a string. I'm struggling to get January to return December and the previous year (ex. if today is Jan 1 2022, I want to return "Dec-21").

Comment: `=EDATE(TODAY(),-1)`?

Comment: `Format$(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmm-yy")`